# C++ Segmentation fault on linux

Tags: c++, linux

Sorry that I am new to c++ and linux, I haven't seen Segmentation fault before. I can successfully compile the file but it just outputs Segmentation fault.

I tried to google Segmentation fault but still no clue on how to fix my code.

Hope someone can rescue me and tell me what's wrong **by specifically stating the line(s) I made errors.**
I would be grateful about that! Many thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <semaphore.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS     36
#define MAX 36

char matrix[6][6]; //result sheet

//queue elements
char queue[MAX], head=0, tail=0;


int row=0,col=0;
int runtime=1; // track the number of times we have run the dispatch 
funciton

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void dispatch(){

    row = runtime / 6;
    sleep(1); //wait 1 second to generate column number
    col = runtime % 6 - 1;
    if (runtime % 6 == 0)
        col = 5;

    runtime++;

}


void enqueue(char c){
    queue[tail] = c;
    tail = (tail+1)%MAX ;
}

char dequeue(){
    char temp = queue[head];
    head = (head+1)%MAX ;
return temp;
}




//master thread
void *qcTask(void *args) {
//simulate product convey delay
   sleep(1);

   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

   dispatch();

   sleep(rand()%6+5);

   if(rand()%100<90)
       enqueue('Q');

   else
       enqueue('U');

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

   pthread_exit(NULL);
}   



int main (int argc, char* argv[]){


   int input = atoi(argv[1]);
    //error handling
   if(argc!=2 || input < 0 || input>36){
      cout<<"Input is illegal!";
   }

   else{
       pthread_t threads[input];


       int rc, i, count = 0;

       srand(time(NULL));

   for(i = 0;i<input;i++){

       rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, qcTask, NULL);
       if (rc){
           cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;
           exit(-1);

     }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < input; i++){
       rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
       if (rc){
           cout << "Error:unable to join," << rc << endl;
           exit(-1);
       }
           }

    //initize matrix with default value 'i'
   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
           matrix[i][j] = 'I';
       }
   }

   //fill the result sheet
   for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            matrix[i][j]=dequeue();
        }

   }

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
       for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++){
           cout << matrix[i][j];
           if (matrix[i][j] == 'U')
               count++; 
       }
       cout << endl;
   }

   cout << count << " products are unqualified.";
   pthread_exit(NULL);

   }
}
```

Comment: run your code using valgrind

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: This code is correct just pass an argument for example: ./command 4

Answer (score 3):

A segmentation fault (segfault / SIGSEGV) simply means that the OS detected that your program tried to access memory outside of its allocated address space. There can be *many* reasons for this (almost always caused by bugs in *your* code).
Examples include:

- dereferencing an uninitialized pointer
- writing past the end of an array (or other container)
- dereferencing a nullptr
- writing to or reading from free'd memory

And many more..

Comment: *"There is some memory related issue in your code"* is not a terribly useful answer.

Comment: It is if the question is WTF a segfault means...which is the only redeemable part of the OP.

Comment: @Baum mit Augen - the poster seemed confused about what a segfault is/means - I simply try to explain that.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I would be even happier if anyone can point out which line(s) of my code is(are) wrong.